# Verbal subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

This is from a book on group theory:

[image: Image 1]

What is the role of $F$ here? $F$ seem to have nothing to do with $G$. Is perhaps $G$ the presentation $G=F/W^F$?

Comment: You have to have $F$ in order to make sense of $w$.

Comment: If you take *any* group instead of a free one there are going to be non-trivial relations among its generators. That would turn making sense of word something very hard.

Comment: I see. Thanks. [EMPTY]

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Derek Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups, 2nd edition.